# Where should scripting be placed with Alpine?

Tags: alpine.js

With vue, I would have a vue component (`.vue` file) that contained the markup and javascript in one file. This component would be imported into a master javascript file for deployment and hashed and uploaded to something like S3/Cloudfront.

With Alpine, I've made a few basic components, but where should any additional javascript sit?

So for example, I have a PHP file for a feed, when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, I need to load more posts. The markup is in a PHP file, but where should the javascript sit? If it's within the same PHP file, how can I benefit from uploading the javascript to S3/Cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the functions used in `x-data` in a JavaScript file using Laravel Mix to compile the file together. For example with `<x-data="search()"></div>`, the `search` function could be placed in a JavaScript file (eg. `function search() {}`) as long as Alpine is able to access the function, with some bundlers that means you'll need to use something like `window.search = function() {}`.